# Autocomplete Textbox

Tags: asp.net-ajax

my autocomplete textbox is not working m using visual studio2008.i hav included AjaxControlToolkit.dll in my directory but still getting an error like "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"
what does it mean m not getting

Answer (score 1):

Is this local, or deployed to a server. If it is local make sure you add a reference to the DLL. If deployed make sure the reference has the "Copy Local" property set to true in order for it to be included when published.

Comment: its local and i hav registered that dll in my file but still giving error

Comment: Can you detail your environment more. It is not finding the DLL. Is it in the BIN directory. Post a screen shot of your solutions explorer with bin and references expanded.

Comment: hav include dll in BIN folder now not giving error but still not working here is my aspx source code

Comment: now my webmethod is not getting hit so that textbox is not working though not giving any error

Comment: That seems to be a different issue altogether, may I suggest a new post with complete details.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the DLL is compiled the wrong way. If the DLL is an explicit x86 (or x64) build instead of an "All CPU" build you will also get these errors when you use that DLL in an application build for all CPU.

I have seen this happen with a dll compiled explicitly for x86 which was used in an application which was compiled with "all cpu" running on a x64 machine.